# Getting No such file or directory error when i use shell from oozie

Tags: shell, hadoop, oozie, oozie-workflow

i am trying to run shell script from oozie, when i am using hadoop commands inside shell script, it's working fine but when i am trying to run local commands, i am getting no such file or directory exception.
Example:

```
sample.sh
hadoop fs -touchz /user/123/test.txt
```

this script is working, when i use NFS path or local path i am getting 
"No such file or directory" exception,
Example:

```
sample.sh
touch /HDFS/user/123/test.txt
```

is there anything i am missing, please let me know, '/HDFS' is NFS path.

Comment: NFS? Did you mean HDFS?

Comment: No NFS(Network File System) path only.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is all the Oozie workflows will be executed by the Oozie server so if you have the directory `/HDFS/user/123` created already in the Oozie server, it will work.

So the solution to make it work would be configuring the NFS to work with (attach) the Oozie server.

**Update**

After clarifying some of my own unknowns, what I had mentioned above is not entirely correct. Here is my updated answer:

When you, the client, submit the Oozie job, with YARN, it goes to the ResourceManager which then negotiates and routes it to any of the NodeManagers, so for your case to work, you would have to have the NFS mount configured on all of the NodeManagers to work properly.

Comment: No, Oozie starts YARN containers, so it can run on any NodeManager

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. The primary node manager is where the Oozie server will be running, no? So I meant that the NFS path should be configured to be available from that node (primary node manager)

Comment: There's no such thing a "primary" NodeManager. Oozie Server is a standalone process outside of YARN. Oozie tasks can run on any machine in the YARN cluster. Meaning the NFS mount would need to be on each of those

Comment: Agreed. I got confused with `ResourceManager`. Typically when the stack is configured for HA, there would be `active` and `secondary` ResourceManager. And yeah, the NFS mount should be configured on each of those.

Comment: By default oozie will run in mapreduce mode, when i am trying to redirect output to a file in edge node, it is giving me no such file or directory error, because it is searching that folder in other data nodes, i resolved this issue by redirecting output into a file in container path and moved from there. I know, if the issue is just related to redirecting output i can use hadoop fs -appendToFile - command but, i am trying to run one script also so, i copied all code to container path, which resolved my issue.